# Eclipse CDT- Is there a way to kill previous running launches before starting new one?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am developing a C++ project using Eclipse CDT. At times, when testing my code, I forget to kill the process that is currently running. I do some changes to the code and run it again which now runs as another process. This overtime builds up and eats my RAM and CPU. Only then I realise I have not destroyed the previous processes and I go to the corresponding consoles and kill them by pressing the red button.

So, I want to know if I can somewhere set a rule in eclipse that If I run the project again, It should automatically kill the existing running processes and then spawn the new one?

Comment: I don't know how you can do this in eclipse, but if there is a way to let eclipse run a command before building/starting the executable, then you can use something like `pkill your_executable_name` or `killall your_executable_name` too kill the process if there is any running.

Comment: @triple_r This is what I am doing manually outside eclipse in a terminal. Do you know how to add this in front of eclipse's run command?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not that familiar with eclipse. There is a place in project options that let's you specify the executable. Just throwing this on the table: can you change the executable to something like `pkill aaaa; ./aaaa` instead of plain `./aaaa`?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to update your makefile to run a script that kills the executable before it attempts to perform the link.

```
# Link the executable
$(EXE_NAME) : $(LIBS)
    @echo killing exe
    -(cd path/to/script; ./kill.sh)
    @echo Linking
    $(CXX) ...
```